# How to backup only the photos in Picasa Albums?

Tags: backup, picasa

I've got a lot of photos, ~100GB worth. Most of these are discards, I organize my photos with Picasa so I've got the best ones in albums (~10GB worth). I'd like to backup only these photos (it's to Dropbox, so uploading all of them is not possible), is that possible?

Comment: What OS are you using (Windows/OS X/...?

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in [Backup Tool](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=11068). You can select which folders and/or albums will be included in the backup

Create a new backup set and select `Disk-to-disk backup`. Then select your Dropbox folder as the destination.

Comment: Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: It's not possible to schedule it from Picasa. Unfortunately looks like there's no (known) command line options as well. Maybe [sync to web](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?topic=16049) is an option for you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get Dropbox to only backup specific folders using a [symblink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).